# JW Player can't play mp4 video downloaded from youtube

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, mp4, jwplayer

I have doenloaded am mp4 video using IE Realplayer plugin from youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3a80c5Ar3Y

I have a test site on my local machine where I have HTML5 JW Player.

I download the video and then play locally using realplay to see if it plays.
I notice that not all mp4 downloads from youtube plays in Realplayer.
The ones that play in Realplayer also play in JW Player on local website. 
But the mp4 files that don't play in Realplayer also don't play in JW player.

This is the error I get in the player:
the video playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser didnot support mylocalsite/xyz.mp4 undefined

I tested IE, FF, Chrome. It works nowhere.

Here is my jw player setup and html:

```
<video id="container" src="mylocalsite/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" poster="mylocalsite/test.jpg" width="640" height="360"></video>
```

**player setup:**

```
var modes = '';
var swfPath = '/content/jw/player.swf';
            if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(android)/) || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(chrom)/)) {                
                modes = [{ type: 'flash', src: swfPath }, { type: "html5"}];
            } else {
                modes = [{ type: 'html5' }, { type: 'flash', src: swfPath }, { type: "download"}];
            }

jwplayer('container').setup({                
                'flashplayer': swfPath,                
                'width': '640',
                'height': '360',
                'provider': 'video',
                'modes': modes,                
            });
```

Here is the details info about the file returned by ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version 1.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 31 2013 02:49:36 with gcc 4.6.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/c/Users/Administrator/ffmpeg --extra-cflags=-I/c/User
s/Administrator/ffmpeg/include --extra-ldflags=-L/c/Users/Administrator/ffmpeg/l
ib --cpu=i686 --enable-gpl --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree

  libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
  libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
  libavformat    54. 59.106 / 54. 59.106
  libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
  libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
  libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\videos\woh.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2013-09-08 23:34:28
  Duration: 00:03:50.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 189 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360,
187 kb/s, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-09-08 23:34:28
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

What can be causing this issue?

Comment: If I reconvert that mp4 video to another mp4 with ffmpeg, I can play the video in Real player but I lose the audio part. Also the video file size is now only 942KB instead of 5.2MB

Comment: Looks like it is a problem with the download utility Realplayer being used. Realplayer can't handle MPEG-DASH type encoded videos when downloading.

Comment: As long as the file is h264, the player should play it. Where this is running?

Comment: Hi Ethan, Thanks for your comment. It doesn't work. The site is running on my localhost. Does JW Player support MPEG-DASH type videos of mp4? Please help me. Thanks again.

Comment: We do not yet support DASH.